# Remove color overlay from active line with `display-line-numbers-mode`

Tags: linum-mode

Since `linum-mode` is replaced with `display-line-numbers-mode` I'm having an color overlay on the active line, seen in this screenshot as white on the line 77:

[image]

Tried to change the theme and few other modifications but this remains. I'm not doing anything to emphasize line on which my cursor is at, so I'm guessing that shouldn't be the source also.
I tried setting it with both `(global-display-line-numbers-mode t)` and `(display-line-numbers-mode t)` but it's the same.
How could this be removed, or what variable could be set to customize that color?
Additional question: Could I instead of that overlay have slightly different font color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's controlled by face `line-number-current-line`

You can M-x `customize-face` to change it.

and you can learn more from https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Display-Custom.html

Comment: I had a small problem following your answer because `describe` showed nothing for `line-number-current-line`, but when I started digging into `customize-face` I finally understood how it works.

Thanks!

Comment: For those that just need a way to change the color, this is the way:
`(set-face-attribute 'line-number-current-line nil :background "red")`
and because I'm using base16 theme, this was the best looking fringe for me:

`(set-face-attribute 'line-number-current-line nil :foreground (plist-get base16-material-colors :base01))`

`(set-face-attribute 'line-number-current-line nil :background (plist-get base16-material-colors :base04))`